# gradle: execute code depending on the build type (or variant)

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-studio

I want to execute some code depending on the build type (release, debug). specifically, i want to change the APK name depending on the build type ... something like this,

```
if (buildType.name == 'release') {
  project.archiveBaseName = 'blah';
} else if (buildType.name == ...) {
  ...
}
```

I don't know where to put this code however. I can iterate over the build types,

```
android.buildTypes.each{ type ->
    print type.name
}
```

but this of course gives me all the build types, not the current build type.

Comment: Does this help: https://plus.google.com/u/0/118417777153109946393/posts/EATUmhntaCQ

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that buildTypes is the feature you need:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```

Does it help?